# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Lenovo ThinkPad L390 fingerprint driver problem

Tags: gnome, 20.04, lenovo, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

My configuration is:

Laptop: Lenovo ThinkPad L390
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64-bit GNOME (3.36.2)
Kernel: version 5.4.0.-33-generic

I can't seem to find a fingerprint setting even though the laptop has it built-in. Is there a way to set it up? Maybe install some sort of a driver?

Please advise.